# How do i listen for network data from the server in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app for testing the Network framework in iOS and Swift. But how do I create the code so I can receive data from the server, like a listener? Im using a UDP connection.

I've already tried to use the "receive" or "receiveMessage" method, but I can not figure out how to listen all the time. It just receive data when the application connects to the server, but not when the server send to the client app.

```
//This is the receiveMessage approach from the client in Swift:
class UDPClient {

var connection: NWConnection
var queue: DispatchQueue
weak var controller: ViewController?

init() {
    queue = DispatchQueue(label: "UDP Client Queue")

    connection = NWConnection(host: "<secret>", port: 8888, using: .udp)

    connection.stateUpdateHandler = { [weak self] (newState) in
        switch newState {
        case .ready:
            print("ready to send")
            self?.sendInitialMessage()
        case .failed(let error):
            print("client faild with error: \(error)")
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    connection.start(queue: queue)
}

func sendInitialMessage() {
    let helloMessage = "hello from iPhone".data(using: .utf8)
    connection.send(content: helloMessage, completion: .contentProcessed({ (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Send error: \(error)")
        }
    }))

    connection.receiveMessage { (content, context, isComplete, error) in
        if content != nil {
            print("Got message")
            let text = String(data: content!, encoding: .utf8)
            print(text!)
        }
    }
}

func send(content: Data) {
    connection.send(content: content, completion: .contentProcessed({ (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Send error: \(error)")
        }
    }))
}
}

//This is the server PHP code:
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

socket_bind($socket, "<secret>", 0000);

while (true) {
    socket_recvfrom($socket, $buffer, 100, 0, $rip, $rport);

    echo "Received ". $buffer. " from ". $rip . $rport . "\n";

    socket_sendto($socket, "hi", 2, 0, $rip, $rport);
}
```

I want the app to print "hi" when the server send "hi" message by listening for the socket data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement other stateUpdateHandler enum cases, see the doc here 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/state

If you want to have a reliable UDP networking library and not just learning the basics you can use CocoaAsyncSocket and not reinvent the wheel :
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket